# How to generate random 6 digits number by a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

I tried random generate number from 1 to 100.How to change random ***6 digits*** ?

Note :***Numbers can not start with 0(zero)***

Random from 1 to 100 codes

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface RandomNumberGenViewController : UIViewController {

 int number;
 IBOutlet UILabel *label;

 }

 -(IBAction)generateNumber:(id)sender;

 @end



 @implementation RandomNumberGenViewController

 -(IBAction)generateNumber:(id)sender {

 number = (arc4random()%100)+1; //Generates Number from 1 to 100.
 NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
 label.text = string

 }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly, I don't get it?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(900000)+100000`

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Is not clear question ? I want generate random 6 digits.Solved by rmaddy's answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A random number with 6 digits would be:

```
int number = arc4random_uniform(1000000);
```

But that gives a number from 0 to 999,999. It sounds like you want a random number from 100,000 to 999,999. So do this:

```
int number = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
```